# Calculator. I want to add a loop that says ("invalid entry") and re asks the question if the user inputs an incorrect character. Not sure how to do it

Tags: python-3.x, loops, calculator

```
print("Welcome to the calculator!")
print("Enter in the symbol for you desired equation")

math = input("Would you like to ( + ) , ( - ) , ( / ) or ( * )?\n")


if math == '*':
    mult = float(input("Give me the first number you would like to multiply\n"))
    mult1 = float(input("Give me the second number\n"))
    print(mult , "*" , mult1 , "=" , float(mult * mult1))

if math == '/':
    div = float(input("Give me the first number you would like to divide\n"))
    div1 = float(input("Give me the second number\n"))
    print(div , "/" , div1 , "=" , float(div / div1))

if math == '+':
    add = float(input("Give me the first number you would like to add\n"))
    add1 = float(input("Give me the second number\n"))
    print(add , "+" , add1 , "=" , float(add+add1))
```

I want to add a loop function that would basically say 'invalid entry' and loop back to the question again if the user inputs an invalid character.

Comment: Have you attempted to add a for or while loop yet?

Answer (score 1):

replacing the line

```
math = input("Would you like to ( + ) , ( - ) , ( / ) or ( * )?\n")
```

with

```
while True:
    math = input("Would you like to ( + ) , ( - ) , ( / ) or ( * )?\n")
    if math in "+-*/":
        break
    else:
        print('invalid entry')
```

Should get you the behavior you're looking for. The `break` command exits a loop.

You should be able to generalize this for your other input statements.

Comment: Thank you for that! that's exactly what I needed. I was playing around with loops but could figure it out! appreciate it.